# Insert Spreadsheet Macro - Works in 2010 but not 2016

Tags: excel, vba, insert, excel-2010, excel-2016

I have a VBA macro which copies a summary tab from one workbook to another.  It works fine in 2010, but not for our associates who've upgraded from 2010 to 2016.  The macro doesn't error out - it just doesn't do anything at all.  Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be different with 2016?  Thank you!

```
Sub Analyst_Summary_macro()

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim MyPath As String, MyCompletePath As String
MyCompletePath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shtToCopy As Worksheet

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\n0079864\Desktop\Analyst_Summary.xlsx")
Set shtToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Analyst_Summary")

Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open(MyCompletePath)
shtToCopy.Copy wkbDest.Sheets(1)

Workbooks("Analyst_Summary.xlsx").Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: How are they running the macro? Put a MsgBox in the code to see if it is ever called. Or a breakpoint.

Comment: security settings etc

Comment: Why `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at end? Should it not be `True` so screen refreshes?

Comment: `ScreenUpdating` auto-resets to True when code is done running

Comment: Okay, we F8 tabbed through the code, and it works fine until we get to the "shtToCopy.Copy wkbDest.Sheets(1) line. We get no error message at all, it just keeps going and it does close the workbook per the next line.  Also, Firefox - I'm not sure why "False" is at the end (I didn't write the original code), but that particular workbook does not need to be updated as that is where we are just copying the tab from. So if that workbook closes without updates, that is fine.

Comment: Is the the complete code - nothing left out?

Comment: Are you copying into the workbook which has the code, or some other workbook?  Using `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` to open another workbook seem unnecessary (since it's clearly *already* open), and may lead to problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you copying into the workbook which has the code, or some other workbook?

Using `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` to open another workbook seems odd, and may lead to problems.

Try the following changes:

```
Sub Analyst_Summary_macro()

    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook?
    wkbDest.Save

    With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\n0079864\Desktop\Analyst_Summary.xlsx")
        .Sheets("Analyst_Summary").Copy wkbDest.Sheets(1)
        .Close False
    End with

End Sub
```